# IFS read not getting executed completely when using commands over remote in linux

Tags: bash

I am reading a file through a script using the below method and storing it in myArray

`while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a myArray
do
   "do something"
done < file.txt
echo "ALL DONE"`

Now in the "do something" area I am using some commands over ssh

`ssh user@$SERVER "some command"`

But the issue is after executing this for the 1st line of file.txt, the script stops reading the file further and skips to next step that is I get the output

`ALL DONE`

But instead of commands over ssh I use local commands the scripts run file. I am not sure why this is happening. Can someone please suggest what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to try giving the `-n` flag to ssh, from the [manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html):

```
-n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from
             stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the background.  A
             common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote
             machine.  For example, ssh -n shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will
             start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will
             be automatically forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh
             program will be put in the background.  (This does not work if
             ssh needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f
             option.)
```